# Is there an upper bound on the length of time that Gazebo can run?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Posted on the [gazebo issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/679).

(OR phrased another way) How long should (does) Gazebo run for?

If I, run Gazebo with the following world file, is there any reason that the server should terminate after a fixed duration of time?

(e.g. some sort of timeout that activates after X hours)

my.world:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.3">
  <world name="default">
    <physics type="ode">
      <gravity>0 0 9.8</gravity>
      <ode>
        <solver>
          <type>quick</type>
          <dt>0.001</dt>
          <iters>40</iters>
          <sor>1.0</sor>
        </solver>
        <constraints>
          <cfm>0.0</cfm>
          <erp>0.2</erp>
          <contact_max_correcting_vel>100.0</contact_max_correcting_vel>
          <contact_surface_layer>0.0</contact_surface_layer>
        </constraints>
      </ode>
    </physics>
    <!-- A global light source -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <!-- A ground plane -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://create</uri>
      <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://camera</uri>
      <pose>0 0 1 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2478/is-there-an-upper-bound-on-the-length-of-time-that-gazebo-can-run?/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2013-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have let it run for hours and at times overnight. I've never tested it for multiple days. There's no pre-programmed limit that I've seen, but it always has the possibility of crashing or a memory leak dragging your system to a halt. If there's a crash that you see regularly, or if you can get a backtrace with gdb, I'd encourage you to file an issue on the [gazebo issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues).

EDIT: Also, if you are recording a log file (gazebo -r) then you need to watch your disk space because the log files can get big very quickly.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-04-20**:
I will file an issue, I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something obvious. I'm seeing a crash regularly, and I'm trying to gather data about how it happens and the operating environment.  I also need to try with gazebo built from the "real" repo (tested with https://bitbucket.org/osrf/simulator_gazebo)

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-04-20**:
For reference 3 hours 12 minutes is the current run duration (must be a leak somewhere that my op environment is uncovering...)

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-04-20**:
If you are running custom plugins, they may be a source of memory leaks and bugs as well.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-01**:
It could be an issue with the camera plugin. I'll test it on my machine.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-07**:
I just tested it, and you have gravity pointing up, so that the camera and create fly away. I would guess that falling upwards for several hours could lead to a nan or something.